# Sudo into a user, start a process and log it

Tags: linux, debian, sudo

I am trying to run this command:

```
sudo -i -u User-1 /home/User-1/steamcmd.sh +force_install_dir /home/User-1/game +login anonymous +app_update 740 validate +quit >> /home/User-1/game/steam.log &
```

And yes i am logged in with a different user, the user has sudo privileges.

When i am logged in as the same user, without using sudo in this command it works. It seems like there is some kind of issue with >> path & and sudo.

It returns:

```
 bash: /home/User-1/game/steam.log: No permission
```

Seems like the logging command isnt executed on the same user level.
Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Well, yes, the shell does the redirection and then calls `sudo`. That is what your command says to do and hence expected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo -u User-1 bash -c "/home/User-1/steamcmd.sh +force_install_dir /home/User-1/game +login anonymous +app_update 740 validate +quit >> /home/User-1/game/steam.log"
```

Try that

Comment: @Neoon can you try without the `-i` option?